# Outlook Add-in. Place a form instead message pane and reading pane

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010

Can somebody tell me how to display a form in the area marked red, or at least how this area can be reached from my application.
Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display custom form inside the outlook's main window you need customizes an Outlook folder so that it displays an HTML file in its home page window. It can then use this HTML file to host a managed control inside.

[image: Managed control inside the Web View of an Outlook explorer]

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479345.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

An [Outlook View Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff871384.aspx) will let you takeover the currently active view pane.